# How to get selected value from dropdown list in HTML to C#

Tags: c#, sql, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make something that exceed my limits. basically first i am taking some value and write in dropdown list and i am trying to write the selected value to a label. i tried with the code below. but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
                <div class="dropdown show col-md-2 p-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle p-1" href="#" role="button"  id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" runat="server" onserverclick="dropdownMenuLink_ServerClick">Load Evaluation
                    </a>

                    <div id="dropdown" name="dropdown" runat="server" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" >

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div>
                    <label id="dropLabel" runat="server"> merhaba </label>
                </div>
```

C#

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //A3id = A3_Coaching_Main.id;
        //A3id = 51;

        SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("select name from A3_Coaching", con.connection());
        SqlDataReader dr = comd.ExecuteReader();

        A3toSqlDataContext ctx = new A3toSqlDataContext();
        var alp = from c in ctx.A3_Coaching
                  select c.name;

        foreach (var item in alp)
        {



            HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
            anchor.InnerHtml = Convert.ToString(item);
            anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-item");


            dropdown.Controls.Add(anchor);

        }

    }

    protected void dropdownMenuLink_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dropLabel.InnerHtml = Request.Form["dropdown"];
    }
```

Comment: Could you add more info? For example which technology do you use

Comment: in HTML frontend i use bootstrap 4 and C# if i understood right

Comment: If I understand right you are using Asp.Net than you could use SelectedItem property: `Label.Text=dropdown.SelectedItem.Text`